# Update model from database crashed

Tags: c#, database, oracle, entity-framework-6, odp.net

I use ODP.NET tool and Oracle.ManagerDataAccess library to connect from C# app to Oracle DB. I want to update .edmx model. I use Update Wizard for that. First, I choose data connection and when I click next, instead "Choose Your Database Objects and Settings" page, Update Wizard closes. I do not get any error message. What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you installed the Oracle developer tools for Visual Studio? It's been some time, but I do recall running into your situation in the past. If I can recall, it was a library I was missing.

Comment: Yes, Oracle developer tools for Visual Studio is installed.

Comment: Make sure the tools reflect the correct client version (and bit) you're using for Oracle and you're using the correct VS version. I don't think Oracle supports VS 2017, you may have to use VS 2015/13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I have reinstalled ODT for VS15 (ODTforVS2015_121025) and changed a version of Oracle.ManagerDataAccess library (12.2.1100). It helped me.